# calling two javascript function in href for a tag

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to do this :

```
<a id="seeAll" onclick="stopClickEffect(event)" href='
<%# 
  String.Format("javascript:PositionPopup("#MapPos", this);ShowMap(\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\");",   
  Eval("LONGTITUDE").ToString(),Eval("LATITUDE").ToString(),Eval("CASA_NAME").ToString()) 
%>'
class="see_all colored_font">[Show map]</a>
```

But I get the error **Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line**

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please show us what effort you have put into fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should NOT place Javascript code in the `href` attribute. Only use the `onclick` handler. From HTML/Javascript point of view, it is no problem to put more than one function there:

```
<a href="#" onclick="stopClickEffect(event);PositionPopup('#MapPos', this);ShowMap('...');return false;">...</a>
```

The error comes from c# code, I guess you have to escape the `#` and `"` in your code. String.Format escaping is described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma#string.Formatescaping7). You use double curly brackets like this: `"{{...}}"`

I'm not sure what the `stopClickEffect` function does, but maybe you can even leave that out when you `return false` in the end of the `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 2):

The # in front of your String.Format tells the C# preprocessor that this is a preprocessor-directive, like `#region asdf` and `#endregion`.

Because you marked the line with the # it is interpreted as such a directive. And because of the whitespace after the # you get this error message.

To be clean, remove the # from the href, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

it should have been like this

```
<a href = 'http://localhost/abc/' onclick = 'return test()' >
```

And javascript function

```
function test(){

   //you code
   return false // this will not allow href to go to another page

   return true // let href go to another page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to place the code in your `href` attribute in a separate JS function, which you can define outside of that tag. You could then just call that function from the tag, instead of placing all the code there.

That should make it easier for you to fix the problem, and make your code more readable too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JavaScript or HTML have preprocessor directives; however, c# does.

If you are doing something related to c# I'd imagine that the code that is giving you the error is not on the line you linked. A preprocessor directive starts with # and is usually towards the top of your c# code.

The error is saying that you cannot have anything before the # on the line you are using a preprocessor directive. If this line is the line causing issues, it's probably the "<%# string" part. Remove that hash tag and try again.